# Service Portal Modal Window footer

Tags: modal-dialog, servicenow

I created a modal window using spModal found in Github (https://github.com/service-portal/documentation/blob/7893414eded4527db9f98a7a62b0286fc3d3bcf8/documentation/spModal.md).  I'm wondering how to take away the footer of the modal window that contains the Cancel and OK buttons.  I could easily add `buttons: []` to the code, but the footer area is still there and I want to get rid of it completely.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to know what you've done. However `spModal` is a wrapper for Angular UI bootstrap's [$uibModal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#modal).

Take a look at the documentation there and you'll see how these are rendered

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

While you can set the option for the buttons to `buttons: []`, you need to also hide the footer `div`.

Take a look at the rendered HTML and see what the `class` values are for the modal and modal footer. You should be able to use CSS to hide it, if the CSS is predictable.

```
.my-modal .modal-footer {
    display: none;
}
```